# Call Web Service using wget

Tags: web-services, wget

I'm able to call a web service from Linux command line using CURL.
Now I'm tryng to use wget to call a Web Service but I always receive the following error:
**500 Internal Server Error**.

I'm using the following syntax:

```
wget http://<endPoint> --post-file=soapRequest.xml --header="Content-Type: application/soap+xml" --output-document=soapResponse.xml
```

Where soapRequest.xml contains the XML request (validated by SoapUI).

The error returned from wget is:

```
Connecting to <host:port>... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2011-12-12 23:18:33 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```

Answer (score 18):

You don't mention which webserver you are using, or how your URL is formatted, but to invoke a web service operation written in .NET on IIS use this syntax:

> `wget --post-file=soaprequest.xml --header="Content-Type: text/xml" --header="SOAPAction: \"soapaction\"" http://server/app/myservice.asmx -O response.xml`

The "`soapaction`" value can be found in the WSDL, or on the information page ASP.NET creates for the operation at `myservice.asmx`.

Comment: That helps me a lot. Works fine with JBossWS.

Answer (score 5):

I have to use `--header="Content-Type: text/xml"`