# Problems with wget and https soap message

Tags: wget

I have the following request....

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:msgs="<URL FOR NAMESPACE>">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <msgs:service>
       <value>true</value>
      </msgs:service>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This works fine from my local SoapUI, however, I need to run it on a server so per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486516/call-web-service-using-wget) I tried the following...

```
wget --post-file=test.xml --header="Content-Type: text/xml" --header="SOAPAction: \"service\"" <Service URL> -O response.xml
```

But I see the following...

> 2013-06-27 12:37:07 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.

From everything I have researched this server should have access to the url and GET requests using wget to the ?WSDL url. Do I need to change my Content-Type or something?

**Update**

from WSDL...

```
<wsdl:operation name="service">
  <soap12:operation soapAction="pbq:TMP.service" style="document"/>
  ...
```

Comment: Check the server logs.

Comment: I did says invalid SOAPAction I have include the WSDL

Comment: I also tried to use Fiddler with SOAPUI to see what it is putting but it doesn't allow me to decrypt https without trusting a cert

Comment: looking like a problem with the action name not sure yet